# Ubuntu sudoers issue with cmnd_alias

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I have an ansible script that modifies AWS instances. It adds a user to them, and then adds lines to `/etc/sudoers`, so that new user can execute specific commands. I use Cmnd_Alias for the commands, so `/etc/sudoers` looks like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias  BMCCMDS = /bin/cat, /usr/sbin/lsof, /usr/bin/test, /bin/ls, /usr/sbin/dmidecode, /sbin/mii-tool, /sbin/ethtool, /bin/netstat, /sbin/ss
bmcdisc ALL=(ALL:ALL) BMCCMDS
```

**When I try to `sudo lsof`, and type in the password it says**:

**`Sorry, user bmcdisc is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/lsof' as root on`**

This works on centos, rhel, sles and amazon Gnu/Linux, but not ubuntu. The syntax looks identical when reading `man sudoers`. I don't want to give full sudo to the user, just these commands.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l`?

Answer (score 1):

Quite right.

You have permission for `/usr/sbin/lsof`

Comment: ya... could have swore I fixed that :-(  working now, thanks